# How to clear request cache after attempting to multiple request in cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress

Here is my code, I pass array of ids and for each ids I hit Api request.

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      cy.request({
        method: 'GET',
        url: `https://[API endpoint ]/api/v1/[requst]/${ids[i]}`,
        headers: {
          "authorization": token
        }
      })
        .then((res) => {
          return usernames.push([{ value: res.body.instagrams[0].username }])
        })
        .then((res) => {
          return cy.wait(2000)
        })
    }
```

Whenever I execute the code, for 2-3 requests it works fine and then throws error like

```
Uncaught Error: invalid payload
```

I can see my URI is proper and sending correct request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here `cy.request` doesn't work properly with Promise.
Either while pushing it to promise array, remove `cy.request()` or purely handle with javascript.

```
async findUserName(ids, token) {

let promise = []
let usernames = []
ids.forEach(id => {
  promise.push(
    fetch(`https://[host]/api/v1/[endpoint]/${id}`, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        "authorization": token
      }
    })
      .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
      })
  )
})

let result = await Promise.all(promise);
result.forEach((data) => {
  usernames.push([{ value: data.instagrams[0].username }])
})
return usernames
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you should modify your code to wrap all the pending promises into an array. A modified snippet is as below:

```
    async function processRequest(){
      let result;
      let promises = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        promises.push(cy.request({
                         method: 'GET',
                         url: `https://[API endpoint ]/api/v1/[requst]/${ids[i]}`,
                         headers: {
                            "authorization": token
                        }
            }))
     }

      result = await Promise.all(promises);
      for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        usernames.push([{ value: result[i].username }])
      }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! But this is not working :(

Comment: can you please keep the similar code at jsfiddle or somewhere, so that we can look into the error? obviously, there will be some modifications to the above snippet.

Comment: Getting same error above. And sorry brother can't reproduce on jsfiddle because it contains credential